# R-create a data frame with 2 rows in a loop

Tags: r

How can I create a data frame with 2 rows with this structure?

```
X1  Y1 Calc1  X2  Y2 Calc2 … Xn  Yn  Calcn
1   4  0.25   2   5  0.4     i   i+3 i/i+3
```

I tried using this code:

```
dataRowTemp<-numeric(length = 0)
dataRow<-numeric(length = 0)
headerRowTemp<-character(length = 0)
headerRow<-character(length = 0)

    for (i in  1:150){
      X<- i
      Y<- i+3
      Calc <- X/Y
      dataRowTemp <- c(X,Y,Calc)
      dataRow<-c(dataRow,dataRowTemp)
      headerRowTemp <- paste(c("X", i),c("Y", i),c("Calc", i),sep='')
      headerRow<-c(headerRow,headerRowTemp)
    }
```

unfortunately, I can’t create the a correct header (titleRow) and how can I combine them to data.frame later?

Is there an elegant and better way to do so?

Comment: what do you mean by correct header? the variable names? try `names(df) <- c("X1", "Y1" ...)` and to make a data frame out of vectors use `data.frame(a = ..., b = ... etc.)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a function to be used in each iteration.

```
myfun <- function(i) {
  X <- i
  Y <- i + 3
  c(X = X, Y = Y, Calc = X/Y)
}
```

Set the number of iterations.

```
n <- 150
```

Apply the function to the numbers from 1 to n, use `matrix(..., nrow = 1)` to store the output in a matrix of only 1 row, and transform it into a `data.frame` (because it is what you say you aim at).

```
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sapply(seq_len(n), myfun), nrow = 1))
```

Use `paste0` in a loop to iteratively assign names to the column of your `data.frame`.

```
names(mydf) <- c(sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) paste0(c('X', 'Y', 'Calc'), i)))
```